# Unable to Remote Desktop to Windows 7 computers

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Whenever I attempt to RDC to Windows 7 computers I get prompted for a local password.  I think RDC has the domain wrong,

I am able to RDC to any XP box so I know that there's no network problem.  Also, I can tell that if I enter a bad computer name, I get a error on it. So I know that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried forcing the proper domain by using `domain\username` in the username field?

Comment: yes. same problem.

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 RD settings allowing connections from older RDC versions?

Comment: what version of win7 are you using? home professional won't let you remote desktopp into it. and firewall is set allowing remote desktop?